# Django Rest Swagger 2.2.0 Api's on TokenAuthentication not being shown

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-2.0

Currently, I'm using DRF 3.7.7 and Django-rest-swagger 2.1.2, in the following fashion.

### settings.py

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'api_key': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'in': 'header',
            'name': 'Authorization'
        }
    },
    # 'LOGIN_URL': getattr(settings, 'LOGIN_URL', None),
    # 'LOGOUT_URL': getattr(settings, 'LOGOUT_URL', None),
    'DOC_EXPANSION': None,
    'APIS_SORTER': None,
    'OPERATIONS_SORTER': None,
    'JSON_EDITOR': False,
    'SHOW_REQUEST_HEADERS': False,
    'SUPPORTED_SUBMIT_METHODS': [
        'get',
        'post',
        'put',
        'delete',
        'patch'
    ],
    'VALIDATOR_URL': '',
}
```

### views.py

```
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema

class RandomClass(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    schema = AutoSchema(
        manual_fields=[
            coreapi.Field(
                "page_id", 
                required=True, 
                location="query", 
                type="string", 
                description="Facebook Page ID"
           )
    ]
)
```

This allows me to somewhat use drf-schema to render each view individually in swagger docs. The caveat is that, since this view enforces Authentication, only after I authorize an user (authorization by token, as per swagger settings security definitions) I can view all my IsAuthenticated views. Also, If a single view function has multiple methods (get and post) the schema generation for both is same (if I do it this way.
I have two problems here.

- I want to know what would be the proper way to move forward for APIView using TokenAuthentication (I didn't get any useful docs whatsoever and had to scrape forums for a working solution).
- The Authorization procedure for DjangoRestSwagger 2.2.0 does not workwith these settings. As such I cannot use schema encoding, which would be a big help in posting raw json data.

If anyone can help with these issues, or if anyone finds my settings and setup helpful please leave a comment so that we may discuss our options :)